# How to create a reverse formula that will populate a retail price based off of my desired profit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to create a reverse formula that will populate a retail price based off of my desired profit

A2, C2, & D2 are variables that I do not control.

F2 is a variable that is completely subjective - I want my "New Price (G2)" to be calculated based off of the value I input under "Desired Profit (F2)".

[image]

Comment: `=(F2+D2+C2)/.85`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you Scott! That was it :)

Answer (score 1):

I've corrected the formula in `E2` to `=A2*(1-B2)-C2-D2`

The algebra is [image: 0.85x+3.6=10] and the solution [image: x=13.6/0.85]

Once translated back to Excel, you get `=(F2+C2+D2)/(1-B2)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try "desiered profit" minus "current profit" added to "current retail price" (because it needs the base to change it off of) so:
=(F2-E2)+A2

Comment: @espertus - the "typo" you just corrected is in the OP's spreadsheet screendump as well